# Typescript react esbuild unable to build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to build a package and upload it to npm so I tried to create a demo package first.
I used this repo as a starter package:  https://github.com/wobsoriano/vite-react-tailwind-starter

and updated the build script to this

```
  "build-test": "esbuild src/App.tsx --bundle --minify  --outfile=src/dist/index.js",
```

and the App.tsx i updated to this

```
import React from "react";
import "./index.css";

const App = () => {
  return <div>My Dummy</div>;
};

export default App;
```

Then I tried to build it and import it in my main.tsx like this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./dist/index.js";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

And then I get this error:

> The requested module '/src/dist/index.js' does not provide an export
> named 'default

Answer (score 1):

I only can give you a quick manual fix. For some reason the index.js file has no "export default" keywords, but you can open the src\dist\index.js file and you can just insert the "export default " at the very begin. So the begin will look like this:

```
export default ()=>{var K=Object.create;var _=Object.define.
```

Because the whole index.js just a function, you can do this.